# List MS Access tables of existing Access instance from VSTO C# using COM Interop

Tags: c#, ms-access, com, vsto

Using VSTO and COM Interop, I am trying to access and manipulate a database that is already open in Microsoft Access. I can get hold of the Access application object, the current user name, and other properties. But when I try to get a list of the tables to print the table names, the code fails.

My end goal is to run an Access VBA macro using 'application.Run("MyMacroName")'. Can anyone tell me what I am missing or doing wrong?  Thank you.

UPDATE SOLUTION

Thank you to Albert (see below) who kept providing (Visual Basic) information until I was able to get the C# code to work. The biggest things I was missing were 1) the DAO using reference (VStudio said I didn't need it, originally), and 2) an *explicit* DAO TableDef type for the loop ('var' would not work).

UPDATED CODE THAT WORKS:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao;  // *MUST* have DAO as well
using Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access; // Access = a namespace qualifier

[TestMethod()]
  public void MsAccessComInteropTest() {
    // explicitly cast the object to an Access.Application
    // I used 'Access.Application' to qualify from a System.xxxx.Application type
    var app = (Access.Application) Marshal.GetActiveObject("Access.Application");
    Dprint($"{app.Name}"); // prints Microsoft Access
    Dprint($"{app.CurrentUser()}"); // prints Admin

    var db = app.CurrentDb();

    // *MUST* use TableDef type explicitly from DAO in loop - cannot use 'var'
    foreach (TableDef tbl in db.TableDefs) {
      // Attributes == 0 means a user-defined table
      if (tbl.Attributes == 0) {
        Debug.Print($"{tbl.Name}  '{tbl.Attributes.ToString()}'");
      }
    }

    app.Run("MyVbaMacroName");  
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you open a recordset of MSysObjects table? How is this related to running a macro (or did you mean VBA)?

Comment: Hi, my end goal is run a VBA macro with `app.Run("MyMacroName")`. But along the way I thought it would be helpful to print something simple to demonstrate that I had a proper reference to the `Access.Application` object, and could print things from it.

Comment: Nitpicking on terminology - VBA and macros are very different things in Access, try not to mix them in referencing. Either you run VBA procedure or macro, not "VBA macro". So you don't even need tables? Did you try calling VBA procedure?

Comment: What happens if you call `app.OpenCurrentDatabase` giving it the path to your database file?

Comment: @HansUp Using `GetActiveObject` with `app.OpenCurrentDatabase(path,false,"");` on an existing Access instance (w no db open) successfully opens the database and allows me to print the number of tables using the code above. However, no tables show in the UI even though the db is open. `app.Visible = true;` caused an error setting the property. The macro caused no errors, but no open tables are visible. I could not loop over the TableDefs as shown by Erik A below - Intellisense shows no `td.Name` field inside the loop.

Comment: You are using GetActiveObject. This assumes that Access is already running, and has opened a database, right?

Comment: @Kevin Check whether you had more than one Access session open --- maybe a second session existed with no db open in it --- and that is the one your `GetActiveObject` connected to.  If the originally-targeted db was already open in the connected session, `OpenCurrentDatabase` would have thrown an error.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Yes, I intend to always have an active session running with a database file loaded and probably at least one tab (table) open in the Access UI. HansUp, yes, I saw many OpenCurrentDatabase errors when I did as you asked and loaded a new database from a file. I modified my test code to CloseCurrentDatabase, but that failed too when the database had already been closed. I don't know how to code "Is there a database open?" I'm very sure that I only had one Access instance open at any time. I always used GetActiveObject.

Comment: you need a dao reference  for  the  current db object. But  with interop, then with early binding, currentdb is a dao object. see below answer. Also, your "using" statement has  a  "=" in it - that don't look right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a reference to both Access, and also DAO.

These two:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.dll
```

And you need this:

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\
Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\
Microsoft.Office.interop.access.dao.dll
```

And thus your code will look like this:

```
{
Access.Application app;

app = Interaction.GetObject(Class: "Access.Application");
Access.Dao.Database db;
db = app.CurrentDb;
Access.Dao.TableDef tblDef;

foreach (var tblDef in db.TableDefs)
    Debug.Print(tblDef.Name);
 }
```

In fact, you could use late binding, and NOT even reference the interop assembles.

eg this:

```
{
var app = Interaction.GetObject(Class: "Access.Application");
var db = app.CurrentDB;
var tblDef;
foreach (var tblDef in db.TableDefs)
    Debug.Print(tblDef.Name);
}
```

but, if you go 100% late binding, then you not get any intel-sense.

Also, this looks strange:

```
using Access = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
```

Why the  "=" in above - I don't think that looks right.

should be:

```
using Access Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access;
```

So, if you going to reference using interop - you need both Access + the DAO. (and they are different assembles, but use the same name space -  not sure if that an issue in c#, but it is in vb.net

Comment: Hi Albert, thank you for taking the time to provide an answer. I tried using DAO already, but 1) VStudio said the reference was not necessary (grayed it out), and 2) it didn't help me anyway (the same errors occurred). I use C# and the v16.0 versions of the reference libraries; maybe that has something to do with things. I used `using Access = xxx` style because that's what the MS doc examples use, but it didn't make any real difference in my simple code. I have never seen the `using Access xxxx` style before in C#. I will try your of `Interaction.GetObject` to see how far I get.

Comment: the  using should have removed the "Access" - it should just be using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access. as noted, you can use 100% late binding and not even referance the interop as per 2nd example.

Comment: Hi Albert, thank you for your help. I posted a solution and marked your DAO idea as a key part of the answer. I had to use full early binding and an explicit TableDef type in the loop ('var' would not work). Late binding would not work in C# for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a full list of tables, it's usual to use `CurrentDb.Tabledefs`

```
var db = app.CurrentDb(); 
foreach (var td in db.TableDefs) {
    Dprint(td.Name);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Unfortunately, `app.CurrentDb()` returns null on my machine, so the reference to `db.TableDefs` is not possible for the loop.